# Fix titlebar size on GNOME 44 with X11

Tags: fedora, x11, gnome

I'm currently on fedora 38 with GNOME 44 on X11 - specific windows have very small title bars. Here's an example:
[image]

I think this may be an issue caused by my 200% scaling, due to my laptop screen being really high res, and restarting X11 does seem to fix it, but I'd like to find a solution that does not involve me restarting the X11 server each boot. I've tried to change the font size to no avail, the font size doesn't even seem to affect anything. Is there any known solution for this?

Edit: Found the problem, java does not seem to recognize the GUI scale, swing apps have the same issue. Using GDK_SCALE and sun.java2d.uiScale works for the content, but the title bar is still small.

Comment: After almost a month of not solving this, I went back to zorin, where this wasn't an issue. Upvotes sadly don't aid me in fixing this, if someone finally finds out what went wrong, please do add it on this post for everyone else to see.

Comment: I see the same with electron apps, like Visual Studio Code. Might be this bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/2580